# Confused on intensity of light

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wave-particle-duality, intensity

If light behaves both as particle and wave at the same time, does it mean intensity (energy) of light depends on the square of its amplitude and at the same time energy of photons doesn't depend on the square of its amplitude and rather depends on its frequency?

Does it mean that if I increase the EM wave's amplitude the energy of the wave increases but at the same time the energy of photons is not affected at all? I am really confused about this idea. Does it mean that the energy of each photon is unaffected but at the same time the total number of photons emitted has increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the energy of an individual photon depends solely on its frequency. Intensity is a measurement of energy per unit area per unit time. So the intensity of light is simply the energy of all photons passing through a certain area during a certain time.